# Substituir texto por asterisco jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte campo:

```
<input type="number" name="teste_senha">
```

Preciso que, ao digitar algum conteudo, conteúdo este seja substituido por *****, sem perder o seu conteúdo original, podendo ser armazenado num campo hidden.

Como eu consigo chegar a este resultado?

Comment: você ja tentou alguma coisa?

Comment: Não.. ainda não

Comment: mas você quer esconder e mostrar esse conteudo através de uma ação do usuário?

Comment: Exatamente, na verdade, minha ideia é na versão mobile, no campo senha, aceitar somente NUMEROS, ai pensei em fazer assim, montar como type number, e mascarar ao digitar...

Comment: do jeito que eu entendi, você quer substituir os caracteres por **** enquanto o usuário preenche o campo, correto? se sim, você tem que criar um input hidden mesmo, e usar o evento "change" do javascript para ver mudanças no input, ou usar o keyup

Comment: Não, você não tem que usar o `hidden`. Se o campo é uma senha, use o tipo `password` e faça a devida validação com o JS. O que está pedindo é gambiarra. Dê uma lida sobre o atributo `pattern` do HTML 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como comentaram, não faz muito sentido o que você quer, é ter mais trabalho a troco de nada. O HTML já tem atributo próprio para esconder senhas com asteriscos: `type="password"`.

O que você pode fazer, se deseja apenas números no `input`, é fazer uma validação via JavaScript. Usando regex seria uma opção:

```js
function validar(){
   if( /^[0-9]*$/.test($("#campo").val()) && $("#campo").val()){
      alert("Ok!");
   }else{
      alert("Erro! Só são permitidos números");
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="campo" type="password" name="teste_senha">
<br />
<input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="validar()">
```